# apply css to a link within an unordered list on iOS devices only

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
var iOS = ( navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g) ? true : false );

if(iOS) {
   $('ul.dk_options_inner').find('li').find('a').css('font-size', '60px');
}
```

I want to apply the 60px; to the font within the unordered list links (seen below).

```
<ul class="dk_options_inner" role="main" aria-hidden="true">
    <li><a data-dk-dropdown-value="">This artist should sing...</a></li>
    <li><a data-dk-dropdown-value="VoiceDontCloseYourEyes">Don't Close Your Eyes</a></li>
    <li><a data-dk-dropdown-value="VoiceItGoesLikeThis">It Goes Like This</a></li>
    <li><a data-dk-dropdown-value="VoiceHaveALittleFaithInMe">Have A Little Faith In Me</a></li>
    <li><a data-dk-dropdown-value="VoiceAnywhereWithYou">Anywhere With You</a></li>
    <li><a data-dk-dropdown-value="VoiceAnymore">Anymore</a></li>
    <li><a data-dk-dropdown-value="VoiceRun">Run</a></li>
</ul>
```

There are multiple ul.dk_options_inner on the webpage, so I want it to apply to everyone.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: It needs to apply every unordered list (ul.dk_options_inner)

Comment: @Brad - and it should, what exactly isn't working ?

Comment: It does apply to all of them: http://jsfiddle.net/BPbd5/

Comment: I'd recommend using media queries instead, something like this `@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 568px) { ul.dk_options_inner a{ font-size: 60px; } }` - this should match iPhones, iPods and any other devices that fit the query criteria.

Comment: I don't know a lot of js, but shouldn't an if statement also have an else statement?

Comment: @ChrisM - the `else` part is not required.

Comment: I am using dropkick jquery dropdown and realized I should be applying the font size css to the select element and not the unordered li a, thanks, my mistake, but I appreciate all the feedback.

Comment: Is there a reason you wouldn't want to apply this CSS to Android, Windows Phones, bada, Firefox OS and countless other smartphones with different OS? http://browserhacks.com may help you, everything is better than UA-sniffing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it's not the same code. Simply doing `$('ul.dk_options_inner').find('li').find('a').css('font-size', '60px');` will end up looping through every item matching the selector and individually setting the style attribute. This is really inefficient and if you have hundreds of elements, it's going to cause problems.

Changing classes on the items is a better idea, but you still suffer from the same problem in that you're changing an attribute on N items, which could be a large number. A better solution might be to change the class on one single parent item or a small number of parents and then hit the target items using the "Cascade" in css. This serves in most situations, but not all.

```
ul.dk_options_inner.ios-font{
  font-size:60px;    
}

<ul class="dk_options_inner" role="main" aria-hidden="true">
    <li><a data-dk-dropdown-value="">This artist should sing...</a></li>
    <li><a data-dk-dropdown-value="VoiceDontCloseYourEyes">Don't Close Your Eyes</a></li>
    <li><a data-dk-dropdown-value="VoiceItGoesLikeThis">It Goes Like This</a></li>
    <li><a data-dk-dropdown-value="VoiceHaveALittleFaithInMe">Have A Little Faith In Me</a></li>
    <li><a data-dk-dropdown-value="VoiceAnywhereWithYou">Anywhere With You</a></li>
    <li><a data-dk-dropdown-value="VoiceAnymore">Anymore</a></li>
    <li><a data-dk-dropdown-value="VoiceRun">Run</a></li>
</ul>

var iOS = ( navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g) ? true : false );

if(iOS) {
    $('ul.dk_options_inner').addClass('ios-font');
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as the OP's code ?

Comment: it may be doing the same thing, but clearly the code is different